# Logcat messages disappear after a while of showing up?

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

After few minutes of showing `LogCat` disappear. I changed the number of `LogCat` output message to be 10000 from the Window->Preferences->Logcat. But still disappear before reading the whole stack. Any idea why that happens and how to avoid occurring such problem?

Comment: i am facing similar problem in my rooted mobile the system logs are huge so my program log is lost in the sea of system logs

Comment: @IllegalArgument yes, moreover somtimes, when i add a filter, it does not show any thing

Answer (score 0):

You can change your LogCat buffer length, see in :

Window > Preferences > Android > LogCat > Maximum number of LogCat messages in buffer

Set it to 0 for unlimited size

Comment: Thank you, but as mentioned in my question, i have done what did you suggest, and though, it does not work